# Have no problem doing something and have no trouble doing something

Tags: meaning, idioms, connotations

What's the difference between the two phrases? I'm interested in nuances.

For instance.

1. We had no problem/ trouble finding the stolen  item/ finding her a house etc
2. You had no problem/trouble taking advantage of her naivety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To have no trouble doing something" means to find it easy or convenient.

"To have no problem doing something" means not to object to it.

In perhaps less common cases, the second one can also be used in place of the first.

Answer (score 1):

Although the two words overlap, *problem* implies dealing with complications and difficulty.

*Trouble* implies more effort.

I would prefer *problem* in situations involving bureaucracy, especially in dealing with officialdom.

*Trouble* is more a case of fixing a puncture, getting the desk through the front door.

However it is a case of nuance, as you say, with plenty of room for personal preference and disagreement.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Ronald Sole's answer to address your example sentences:

Problem and trouble both imply some kind of *difficult* or *obstacle* to be overcome.  In many cases, these are interchangeable:

> I had no **problem/trouble** passing the course

Your second example sentence, however, implies something different, that the person didn't need to *overcome any moral objection*.  While either *trouble* or *problem* works here, you could consider a word that embodies this idea of doubt, like ["qualm"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/qualm), ["second thought"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/second%20thought), or ["misgiving"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misgivings)

> You certainly suffered no **second thoughts** before taking advantage of her naivety.

Naturally this depends on whether the speaker intends *reproach* or *approval* ... although this might be more a question of tone and context than verbiage.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. I wanted to see though if only one of them could replace qualms, scruples, or misgivings. I personally felt problem was closer to this meaning, especially when used to show disapproval

Comment: @Daniel  Yes, they can replace qualms, especially if expressing approval, *"You certainly had no trouble stealing that old lady's fortune, well done!"*